# How to get a terminaltable to refresh itself with Python?

Tags: python, terminal

I'm posting here today because I'm new to Python (I've just watched Sentdex's matplotlib playlist and that's all) and I'm starting to get a headache with some stuff : how to get a terminaltable to refresh over itself in the terminal ?

Here's my testing code for demonstration purpose :

```
import random
from terminaltables import AsciiTable
from sys import stdout
import time

while True:
    data = [['Header 1','Header 2'], [random.random(),random.random()], [random.random(),random.random()]]
    table = AsciiTable(data)
    stdout.write(table.table)
    stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(5)
```

I've read about some method using `\r`, but this only allows to return at the beginning of the same line, not getting on a previous one. I've also read about curses, but I'm not sure that it can help with **terminaltables**.

Do you think it's actually possible to print a terminaltable over itself ? What method seems the best to do so, if it is actually possible.

Thanks for your advices !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple method utilizing an ANSI escape sequence:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

For a cursor movement, see:
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html

So putting the following at the start of your while loop

```
print("\033[L;CH")
```

will position the cursor at line `L` and column `C` in each iteration. Afterwards, everything you print will appear at this position.

This will work without problems when using UNIX/Linux systems, but won't work with Windows. For a solution see: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Terminal_control/Cursor_positioning#Python

This seems to be the easiest method to achieve what you want, but the best one would definitely be one using curses!

Comment: Your solution is from far the easiest but after checking curses possibilities, I've seen it allows to detect when a key is being pressed, allowing to quit the program nicely, so I've turned to this method instead. So thanks for your answer, it helped !

Comment: @Pynoob: wanna provide your curses solution as a quick code snippets here?